# Where does Windows store its alternative to the INI file (Delphi 7)

Tags: delphi, registry

I normally write my Delphi applications with an INI file saved in the application's own folder:

```
ConfigFile:= ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0), '.ini');
IniFile:= TIniFile.Create(ConfigFile);

try
  with IniFile do
  begin
    // etc
```

However, one particular application I'm writing, I want to use a setup wizard (Inno) and also give users the opportunity to install the app in Program Files (x86)\MyProg.

What is new to me is that Windows doesn't save the INI file in the install directory but "somewhere else".

Uninstalling the app through Control Panel successfully removes all the items from the Program Files (x86) folder (including the folder) but - in common with a lot of programs - if it is re-installed, all the configuration settings are restored.  So they must be stored somewhere that Control Panel | Uninstall doesn't remove.

So my question is where?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: [UAC Folder Virtualization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx)

Comment: You're violating the Windows guidelines by writing to Program Files from your application. That's been verboten since Vista was released (actually XP, but they didn't enforce it until Vista). Writes to Program Files are virtualized to a different folder. Even if you choose to use a 15 year old development tool, you need to adjust your software to keep up with modern versions of the OS.

Comment: Stop looking for the file and learn about the changes introduced in Vista, 11 years ago. Then add an app manifest, stop virtualization, and store the file under the user profile.

Comment: [How to make Delphi programs Vista-aware](http://www.theabsolute.net/sware/delphivista.html) (which as David says is over a decade old) should help.

Comment: Hey John, I recommend you learn about how to explicitly specify a modern location for your configuration files, instead of flinging it into the UAC Folder virtual store, which is what you just did.

Comment: As I've been out of development for 15 or more years I wasn't aware of the Vista issue with writing to Program Files.... Thanks to Ken for the link, it is very helpful. To be honest, if I see machines with Vista on them I throw a bucket of petrol over them and a lit match :)

Comment: @Ken White I chose Delphi 7 as a retirement gift so it's not as though I particularly _choose_ to use a 15 year old development tool but I certainly can't afford to replace it :)

Comment: The mention of Vista should be interpreted as *Windows versions Vista and later*, which includes Win7/8/8.1/10. It isn't really relevant whether you choose or not; the important part was the second half of that sentence. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing files underneath the `Program Files` folders is forbidden by non-admin users.  If an app running as a non-admin user tries to write a file there, and the app does not have an UAC manifest, then Windows protects the `Program Files` folder and silently redirects all access to a VirtualStore folder within the user's profile.

[Common file and registry virtualization issues in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387)

[Windows 7 Application Compatibility Issues …Demystified !!!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chinmay_palei/2011/01/15/windows-7-application-compatibility-issues-demystified/)

In this case, when you write your INI to this file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProg\MyProg.ini
```

It is actually written to this file instead:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\MyProg\MyProg.ini
```

You should change your app to store the INI file in a more appropriate location, such as:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyProg\MyProg.ini
```

Or:

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\MyProg\MyProg.ini
```

[Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/)

Comment: But, as stated above, change where you put the ini file.

Comment: @GerryColl: Yes, the *correct* solution would be to change the way the app behaves to play nice with UAC.  The `Program Files` redirection is to protect the system from badly written code that writes files where they do not belong.  In this case, the file belongs in the user's profile, such as to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyProg\MyProg.ini`. But the OP did not ask *WHY* the file is being written somewhere else, the OP asked *WHERE* the file is being written.  I addressed both in my answer.

Comment: I did try adding a UAC manifest but the program then asks for permission to run which I don't think is suitable for the application.  I need it to be able to run automatically from the Startup folder.
I also like my programs to be 'portable', hence why I normally prefer to save the INI in the same folder.
I've done a bit of a compromise such that the INI is saved in MyDocuments\MyProg\MyProg.ini when MyProg is installed in program Files otherwise, it's saved along with the exe.

Comment: You will be prompted for permission only if you set the `requestedExecutionLevel` to `highestAvailable` or `requireAdministrator`. In this case, `asInvoker` will suffice. `MyDocuments` should only be used for files that the user can consume. Files for the app to consume belong in `AppData` or `ProgramData` instead. You should not be choosing a different folder based on where your app is installed. Stop fighting the rules, you are making things harder for yourself. Microsoft set aside these special folders for a reason.

Comment: I already create a directory in My Documents with three sub-directories to save user-created data but I've moved the INI file to AppData\Roaming\MyProg\Settings\MyProg.ini.  I've put the uac.res file back in with asInvoker.  And I've set a fixed folder location -- as you say, I was really making things harder for myself.  The program allows the user to select different folders for the user-created data anyway. All sorted. Thanks.