# Delphi ini file reading

Tags: delphi, ini

Im stuck and asking for your help te get a solution for reading my ini file back and placing that in my memo1 form with a button.

This is in my text file:

```
[Filename]

Work Time=03-10-2018 15:11
```

Here is some of the code im working with.

```
var
  aWorkTime: string;

procedure TForm1.button2(Sender: TObject):
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;

  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(GetCurrentDir+'\Filename.ini');
try
  aWorkTime := IniFile.ReadString('Filename', 'Work Time', <'none'>);
finally
  IniFile.Free;
end;
end
```

I hope that this is enough information if not please tell me what you are missing from me

Comment: FWIW, `GetCurrentDir` probably isn't what you need. That can change, and is not necessarily the directory of your application.

Comment: Ah yes File needs to be work time yes my bad typed out the wrong name there.  And if i remove {GetCurrentDir} I get a error the error Not enough actual parameters.

Comment: If you want to read the entire ini file into your memo, then use something like `Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FullIniFileName);`.

Comment: To get the file name, use `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'FileName.ini'`. Do not use `GetCurrentDir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `GetCurrentDir` is problematic. The *current dir* may change and doesn't have to be the same directory as where your *.exe* file resides. Rather use [`ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFilePath)

Also, instead of reading the items one by one, to read the entire *.ini* file into your memo, do something like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'FileName.ini');
end;
```

If you only need the work time, then your code is almost there:

```
var
  aWorkTime: string;
  IniFile: TIniFile;
begin  
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'FileName.ini');
  try
    aWorkTime := IniFile.ReadString('Filename', 'Work Time', '<none>');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Work Time=' + aWorkTime);
  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: ...Or if your Delphi version supports it, `TPath.Combine()` which takes care of the delimiter.

Comment: @Jerry: indeed. Will post that too.

Comment: "*if you are not sure that `ExtractFilePath` returns a trailing path delimiter*" - [it does](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFilePath), especially when using a full filename like `Application.ExeName` for its input.

Comment: @Remy: Yes, it apparently does. Removed that.

Comment: This was kinda fine in the WIndows XP days but Vista and latter you will be fighting UAC if the EXE is in either of Program Files directories.  See the answer to this question for an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276360/where-does-windows-store-its-alternative-to-the-ini-file-delphi-7

Comment: @Brian I agree, but comment probably belongs on the question itself instead :-)

Comment: @Brian: Yes, that is true, but that was not the question. Probably it doesn't matter for the OP (or not yet <g>).